# "Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname" in Pentaho kettle email step

Tags: email, smtp, kettle

I am just trying to send test email using email step in kettle Transformation.

I am giving correct server name and port. I am able to configure email with same settings in ThunderBird outlook and working fine.

However, I am getting following error when I am using same settings in Kettle Email step and email is not sending.

**Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 : Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname**

Pls help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to check, did you specify a fully qualified hostname ? Something like mysmtpserver.mydomain.com ? 
Outlook is smart enough to replace a local name with a fully qualified name.